# Shell: Dont index folders Icon when perfoming `find` / Skip empty folders

Tags: macos, shell, csv, find

I use below code to find the oldest file in the directory:

```
find /Volumes/Hams\ Hall\ Workspace/Tabletop\ 7_WIP -type f ! -name '.DS_Store' ! -name '.uid' ! -name 'Thumbs.db' \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lUr | head -n 1 >> ~/Desktop/test.csv
```

It works most of the time. Although, if directory is empty and has custom Icon, it indexes the Icon, and outputs as if it is the oldest file. Although, if the directory is not empty, it will work as normal.

How would you go on skipping the `Icon` ? Or if the folder is empty, simply skip it entirely?

I've tried excluding it with:

1. `! -name 'Icon'`
2. `-not -path dir`
3. `-type d \( ! -name dir \)`
4. `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`
5. Tried to find out if Icon is `file` or `directory` with both `-f` and `-d`. Both output that Icon doesn't exist. Yet the `Icon` still shows up in the log.

   `if [[ -f /Volumes/Hams\ Hall\ Workspace/Tabletop\ 7_WIP/Icon ]]
   then
       echo the file exists > ~/Desktop/xxx.csv
   else
       echo the file does not exist >> ~/Desktop/xxx.csv
   fi`

Either I am havig somewhere a syntax error, or something goes wrong after `find`, as none of the above worked.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks! I've tested it just now, although, It didn't help :( I am now wondering would writing an If statement could help. E.g.: if path ends with `Icon` simply //do nothing// skip it? On macos, custom icons don't have an actual path do they? As usually they are simply copy/pasted directly onto the thumbnail. Which makes it impossible to find its actual path?

Comment: Well I thought Icon was a directory. I don't know anything about MacOS, sorry